# Django: How to save a formset with a custom model form?

Tags: django, django-forms

Trying to save a bunch of objects but with a custom form:

```
class CustomForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Widget
    complexify = models.BooleanField()
```

When complexify is checked, i need to do some complex operations on the widget object.

I can't do:

```
for object in formset.save(commit=False):
    ...
```

because it won't have the `complexify` flag.

And going through each form seems to be the wrong way:

```
for form in formset.forms:
    ...
```

because it includes the extra (empty) forms and the deleted forms.

Any ideas on how to get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer i could find to this problem was overriding the `save` on the form:

```
class CustomForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Widget
    complexify = models.BooleanField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super(CustomForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        obj.complexify = self.cleaned_data.get("complexify")
        return obj
```

then it will be available for you when you handle them:

```
for object in formset.save(commit=False):
    if object.complexify: 
        object.do_complicated()
```

Comment: There is a missing `*`: `def save(self, *args, **kwargs):`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem, needing to update a field in my forms before saving them. My solution was to do something like what you suggested above, but then skip over forms that hadn't been changed by using the method has_changed, like so:

```
for form in formset.forms:
    object = form.save(commit=False)

    if form.has_changed():
        #make additions to object here
        object.save()
```

I've never worked with the complexify flag, but your question seemed to run along the lines of my own problem, so I thought I'd pass the info along. Of course, if anyone sees anything that will lead to problems later with this approach, please let me know, I'm still a Django beginner.

Comment: I actually tried this, but if you can also delete them, you've got another thing to check for there. I was hoping that there was a built in django way that would take care of the deletes too.